# Compilation time for initialized vector of vectors of strings

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying a C++ program where I have initialized a 2D vector as string. The vector is large though.

```
vector< vector <string> InVector ={ {"Alpha1","Beta1","10.23","13.20"},
                                    {"Alpha2","Beta2","30.23","13.20"},
                                      ..
                                     .. 
                                   };
```

The vector InVector is large — in my case it is 1000x4.

When I compile the program it takes too much time to compile; however, without fixed initialization of the vector it compiles very fast. With -O2 or O3 optimization the time is too much.

Here is output from -ftime-report

> TOTAL : 79.02 0.67 80.53
>   314571 kB

Any idea how I can improve the compilation time.

Shall I initialize it as a array and then convert it to vector? Or is there any alternative to this approach.

PS: If I read this vector from  a file then there is no problem.

Comment: Remember: Compilation is something you do only one time (or very few times anyway), but you will be running the program many times (probably). If you add up the time compiling, compared to the time used for runtime-initialization, which do you think will be more? The answer in most cases is that it will be the initialization during runtime that will be the biggest after a few times. Better have long compilation time, than long runtime.

Comment: what happens if you specifically disable optimisation for this one compilation unit?

Comment: which exact compiler & version are you using? On which system ?

Comment: Why ever hardcode huge chunks of data into an executable? Reading it from a file is a no-brainer. Remember, "constants aren't, variables won't".

Comment: g++ in fedora with -std=c++11 option Thanks mods for correcting my post. This is the best part i like.

Comment: Alnitak still it is 5 times more than reading from a file.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Is this it "Shall I initialize it as a array and then convert it to vector?", if so it should be closed as opinion based. Or are you actually asking how to make compilation time shorter at the expense of run-time? Which is bizarre enough, that IMO should be clearly stated. Also, it kind of looks like a XY problem.

Comment: I'll gladly trade 10 minutes extra compile time if the alternative is that my program takes 2 minutes longer to start (based on the "5 times" comment). A suggestion: put this data structure in a file you will compile rarely, maybe a compilation unit by itself, so it impacts only a build-from-scratch, not your incremental builds.

Comment: @DavidK: I would choose faster startup in the release build, but during debugging I'd much prefer to minimize (compile time + single startup)

Comment: @snoze: Why are you using vectors here?  Do the values get overwritten at runtime?  Do the number of values change at runtime?  Do the number of fields per row vary?  Consider a plain old array.  Why are you storing string representations of numeric data?  I suspect that a strongly-typed aggregate would be better and also faster.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: You might cleverly be able to maintain two versions of the code, one to compile only for debug and the other only for release. But really it's not (compile time + single startup), it's (_first_ compile time + a single startup after _every_ compile).

Comment: @DavidK: In the case where you are stomping compile errors, the executions/compile ratio may well fall below 1.0

Comment: @Ben Voigt: I'm counting on putting the big array in its own compilation unit. As long as _it_ doesn't have bugs, I compile it only once. (If you're going to have to intensively debug the data in that array, then maybe it's worth reading it from a file until it's correct.)

Comment: @Ben Q.Why are you storing string representations of numeric data? Ben, End of the process I need to retrieve the header and value of each vector. That's why you see two strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two options, there may be others:

- Initialize a static array, and then initialize the vector from that.
- Continue using the vector initialization, but put it in a file by itself so it only recompiles when you do a full project build or change the data. And if you're changing the data often they shouldn't be hardcoded into the program but instead provided as a resource or data file.